# Sending variable number of request parameters to moco

Tags: json, mocking

I am using a standalone moco server ([see here for more about moco](https://github.com/dreamhead/moco)) to simulate json request to a server and get corresponding json responses.

My configuration file for a given scenario looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "request": {
            "headers" : {
                "JSESSIONID" : "awK325Su2489Urw44G-5JIMH"
            },
            "json": {

                        "sport":"boxing",
                        "cuptype":"world-wide",
                        "comparison":"best",
                        "number":"all"
            }
        },

        "response": {
            "headers" : {
                "JSESSIONID" : "awK325Su2489Urw44G-5JIMH"
            },
            "json": {

                        "publicResultMessage":null,"updateServicePack":null,"checkbookFormat":1,"requestId":"67CDCECA","checkBookType":25,"servicePackContent":null,"deliveryType":1,"serviceId":24,"serverDate":"2015-05-13T16:08:37.942Z","upgradeApplicationMessage":{"writtenLeftToRight":null,"language":null,"data":null},"publicResultCode":0,"upgradeApplication":"0","errorCode":null,"debugMode":false,"supportNumber":"ABCD15484PPLKI","upgradeApplicationUrl":null
            }       
        }
    }

]
```

This is working correctly: everytime we send the json request with the above request datas along with the JSESSIONID value among the headers moco serves the right configured json response.

Then the specification evolved and **I was required to be able to serve the same response no matter how many additional parameters were added to the request**. It means that if the json section of the request would contain a new parameter such as the "now" datetime (obtained for example with `(new java.util.Date()).toString()`, it should still be able to serve the same json response. This looked like a serious challenge at first, but I've found out about moco's `contain`operator and realized that **the issue could be solved if I applied the contain operator to the known part of the request**.

Unfortunately I could not find a way to apply it on a the json formatted request but only on the request as a text. It means that **when I apply the contain operator my request would look to something like**:

```
"request": {
   "text": {
      "contain":"text that should appear in the request"
   }
},
"response": {
  "json": {
      "userToken":"Hys8475KLO451",
      "deviceId":123
  }
}
```

Now applying this to my initial json request would force me to transform the json to text, adding escaping characters all the way and will make the json looks like:

```
"\"sport\":\"boxing\",\"cuptype\":\"world-wide\",\"comparison\":\"best\",\"number\":\"all\""
```

Which is really ugly. **But the good news is it is working fine**. However I would like to know if contain can be directly applied to json (without formatting it into raw text) and how? And also by what other mean can we get the same result with moco? Thanks.